# Custom naming kernel so it is shown by "uname -sr"

Tags: kernel

I am kinda beginner to Ubuntu and I have been given a task to download the kernel update and custom name it so that after updating when someone type `uname -sr` it should show that custom name instead of kernel version.

That is, if teacher execute command `uname –r`, it must
display my roll number as kernel version.

I have updated the kernel and now want to change the name but don't know how to do that. I searched Google and YouTube but didn't find anything for this.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Your question is not really specific to ubuntu, which may have been the reason why you didn't find an answer online. This question has already been asked and answered at [U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136959/285436).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the linux kernel and not ubuntu specific. Has been asked and answered on Unix&Linux

Comment: @danzel [Are “not only Ubuntu-specific” questions on-topic?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14523/are-not-only-ubuntu-specific-questions-on-topic)

Comment: The option you are after can be seen using `menuconfig` and is under 'General setup ----> Local version - append to kernel release. Conventionally you would use a '-' character before your identifier. My own system shows: `5.5.7-ads` as I have added `-ads` in that section....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ask here, than I assume you use Ubuntu. [Here](https://blobfolio.com/2018/06/building-a-custom-xanmod-kernel-on-ubuntu-18-04/)'s the instruction, how could you compile your own kernel with renaming it based on xanmod. I use this instruction because of I've used it in the past and I was proceeding successfully on 19.10 Lenovo G55.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential bison flex gcc-8 g++-8
# It is also good to verify which version of GCC runs
# by default.
gcc -v

# If an older version of GCC pops up, you should update
# the default choice. update-alternatives is the preferred
# way to handle stuff like this, which you can achieve with
# something like the following:
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-8 800 --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-8
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc

git clone https://github.com/xanmod/linux.git xanmod --branch 4.17
# You could try other branch release

cd xanmod
make clean

make menuconfig
# It is if you want to modify something. When it will be opened, just Save and Exit.

make localmodconfig
# Any module deemed unnecessary will automatically be removed from your existing build config.

make -j2 deb-pkg LOCALVERSION=-custom
# custom here is what your teacher asks for
```

Installing:

```
sudo dpkg -i ../linux-headers*.deb ../linux-image*.deb
```

Reboot into new kernel and try `uname`